# Appium find element by XPath - two elements have same xpath

Tags: appium

I have problem testing news up ... I need to getAttribute("name") from page in app so I could compare the title of the news. To locate this title I used:

```
String storyTitle = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.view.View[@index ='1']").getAttribute("name");
```

But there is a problem because above this title there is another element that has the same xpath and I get it's content instead of the content I want.

Here is UIAutomator View of those elements:

[What I get](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=863D942333D6A4CB!337&authkey=!AMwEBm254SDBD-I&v=3&ithint=photo%2CPNG)

[Content I would like to get](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=863D942333D6A4CB!336&authkey=!AODQa04l9UgXtus&v=3&ithint=photo%2CPNG)

I need to take that title in content-desc from element so I could compare it with title on previous screen that I pulled out of the news, but I don't know how to skip the first element, and go to the second one, because they have all the options the same exepc content-desc, and I can't use that. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `findElementsByXPath` and get the "name" attribute of required occurrence of the element, in your case its 2nd occurrence - `get(1)`.

```
String storyTitle = driver.findElementsByXPath("//android.view.View[@index ='1']").get(1).getAttribute("name");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have a problem. When I put this line I get Error for that line od code: 

"The method get(int) is undefined for the type WebElement". 

If I choose to "Add cast to method receiver" then I get error: 

"The method get(String) in the type RemoteWebDriver is not applicable for the arguments (int)".

The same error happens if I choose to cast it in WebDriver instead in RemoteWebDriver :(

Comment: Okay. Can you please post your updated code? I hope you are using "findElementsByXPath" (it will provide you the list of elements).

Comment: Sorry Surya, my mistake - the problem was that I used findElementByXPath, instead of findElementsByXpath, as you wrote :) I tried and it works like a charm .. just need to trim some text added by app at the end of the second title, but it solved my problem :)
Thanks again! :)